# Variable name to String

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary of CParam with Register as the Key,

CParam has one field that is read from external text file and Description is used as a key to read in HumanDesc.

Text file is a translation file and Description has to be a string.
Something Like this

```
PLACE_HOLDER1 "First Place where things are put"
PLACE_HOLDER2 "Secod Place where things are put"
.....
```

I can easily do this by inserting Register as and putting it in quotes. But There is a 100's of register and it would be tedious(and not very elegant). 
Is there a way that constructor could handle that for me.

Below is a very simplified example of what I ma trying to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Var2String
{
    public class CParam
    {
    public ushort Register;
    public string Description;
    public ushort Content;
    public string HumanDesc;
    public CParam(ushort t_Register, string t_Description, string t_HumanDesc, ushort DefaultVal)
    {
        Register = t_Register;
        Description = t_Description;
        Content = DefaultVal;
        HumanDesc = t_HumanDesc;
    }
};

static class Device1
{
    public const ushort PLACE_HOLDER1 = 0x0123;
    public const ushort PLACE_HOLDER2 = 0x0125;
    public const ushort PLACE_HOLDER_SAME_AS_1 = 0x0123;
    public static Dictionary<ushort, CParam> Registers;
    static Device1()
    {
        Registers = new Dictionary<ushort, CParam>()
     {
       {PLACE_HOLDER1, new CParam(PLACE_HOLDER1,"PLACE_HOLDER1","Place One Holder",100)},
       {PLACE_HOLDER2, new CParam(PLACE_HOLDER1,"PLACE_HOLDER2","Place Two Holder",200)}
     };
        /*
         * Like to be able to do this
         * And constructor CParam
          Registers = new Dictionary<ushort, CParam>()
     {
       {PLACE_HOLDER1, new CParam(PLACE_HOLDER1,"Place One Holder",100)},
       {PLACE_HOLDER2, new CParam(PLACE_HOLDER1,"Place Two Holder",200)}
     };
        */
    }

}
class Program
{
    static private string LookUpTranslationFor(string Key)
    {
        string Translated = "Could not find Val for " + Key;
        //This would read XML file use Key to get translation
        return Translated;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Device1.Registers[Device1.PLACE_HOLDER1].HumanDesc);
        Console.WriteLine(Device1.Registers[Device1.PLACE_HOLDER2].HumanDesc);
        Device1.Registers[Device1.PLACE_HOLDER2].HumanDesc = LookUpTranslationFor(Device1.Registers[Device1.PLACE_HOLDER2].Description);
        Console.WriteLine(Device1.Registers[Device1.PLACE_HOLDER2].HumanDesc);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what i understand you right, but if you register variables is not const you can do something like this:

1.Add another constructor to CParam

```
public class CParam
{
    ....

    public CParam(Expression<Func<ushort>> ex, string t_HumanDesc, ushort DefaultVal)
    {
        Content = DefaultVal;
        HumanDesc = t_HumanDesc;
        Description = ((MemberExpression) ex.Body).Member.Name;
        Register = ex.Compile().Invoke();
    }
};
```

2.Chage your device class like this:

```
internal static class Device1
{
    public static ushort PLACE_HOLDER1 = 0x0123;
    public static ushort PLACE_HOLDER2 = 0x0125;
    public static ushort PLACE_HOLDER_SAME_AS_1 = 0x0123;
    public static Dictionary<ushort, CParam> Registers;

    static Device1()
    {
        Registers = new Dictionary<ushort, CParam>()
                        {
                            {PLACE_HOLDER1, new CParam(() => PLACE_HOLDER1, "Place One Holder", 100)},
                            {PLACE_HOLDER2, new CParam(() => PLACE_HOLDER1, "Place Two Holder", 200)}
                        };
    }
}
```

Note what this would not work with const variables!

Comment: Yes this would do it. I looked into Exression before, I was trying to avoid using Linq also PLACE_HOLDERS1 can not be changed. But otherwise this does work, and I will use it if I find no other solution.

Comment: I can't use readonly in case statements, and case is used in many places in existing code.

Answer (score 0):

To get variable name you need to use Reflection class but you cant use Reflection on Value types

Answer (score 0):

You could build a class containing the desired properties with [`Reflection.Emit`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121568/Dynamic-Type-Using-Reflection-Emit), but to me it feels hacky and you'll lack IntelliSense since the members will be generated at runtime (causing the same problems you are having using strings).

If the file structure is solid and can be depended on, why not create a little utility that generates a class file from the configuration file? You can then either use the class as a placeholder, filling the members with the data from the configuration file at runtime (using Reflection to map properties from the class to properties from the file), or set the data in the class directly.

You can then add this configuration class to your project and convert it to a dictionary if desired.